# AuthenticationFailed: While fetching file stored to azure storage using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, azure

I am using ruby-2.7.0 and Rails 6.0.3.3. I uploaded the file to azure storage successfully and got the URL for it. While accessing the URL, I am getting the following error.

```
<Error>
 <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
 <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization 
header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:c87f3e57-a01e-000a-748b- 
8aa65d000000 Time:2020-09-14T11:38:20.3226191Z</Message>
<AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature fields not well formed.</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

My code to upload the file.
When using s3 service, made this URL publicly available by adding acl: 'public-read' but I need to use azure storage service. So couldn't make the URL publicly available.

file name: `app/lib/active_storage/service/azure_storage_service.rb`

```
require "active_support/core_ext/numeric/bytes"
require "azure/storage"
require "azure/storage/core/auth/shared_access_signature"

module ActiveStorage
  class Service::AzureStorageService < Service
  attr_reader :client, :blobs, :container, :signer, :public

def initialize(storage_account_name:, storage_access_key:, public: true, container:, **options)
  @client = Azure::Storage::Client.create(storage_account_name: storage_account_name, storage_access_key: storage_access_key, **options)
  @signer = Azure::Storage::Core::Auth::SharedAccessSignature.new(storage_account_name, storage_access_key)
  @blobs = client.blob_client
  @container = container
  @public = public
end

def upload(key, io, checksum: nil, **)
  instrument :upload, key: key, checksum: checksum do
    handle_errors do
      blobs.create_block_blob(container, key, IO.try_convert(io) || io, content_md5: checksum)
    end
  end
end

def download(key, &block)
  if block_given?
    instrument :streaming_download, key: key do
      stream(key, &block)
    end
  else
    instrument :download, key: key do
      handle_errors do
        _, io = blobs.get_blob(container, key)
        io.force_encoding(Encoding::BINARY)
      end
    end
  end
end

def download_chunk(key, range)
  instrument :download_chunk, key: key, range: range do
    handle_errors do
      _, io = blobs.get_blob(container, key, start_range: range.begin, end_range: range.exclude_end? ? range.end - 1 : range.end)
      io.force_encoding(Encoding::BINARY)
    end
  end
end

def delete(key)
  instrument :delete, key: key do
    blobs.delete_blob(container, key)
  rescue Azure::Core::Http::HTTPError => e
    raise unless e.type == "BlobNotFound"
    # Ignore files already deleted
  end
end

def delete_prefixed(prefix)
  instrument :delete_prefixed, prefix: prefix do
    marker = nil

    loop do
      results = blobs.list_blobs(container, prefix: prefix, marker: marker)

      results.each do |blob|
        blobs.delete_blob(container, blob.name)
      end

      break unless marker = results.continuation_token.presence
    end
  end
end

def exist?(key)
  instrument :exist, key: key do |payload|
    answer = blob_for(key).present?
    payload[:exist] = answer
    answer
  end
end

def url(key, expires_in:, filename:, disposition:, content_type:)
  instrument :url, key: key do |payload|
    binding.pry
    generated_url = signer.signed_uri(
      uri_for(key), true,
      service: 'My azure storage',
      permissions: 'rw',
    ).to_s
    payload[:url] = generated_url
    generated_url
  end
end

def url_for_direct_upload(key, expires_in:, content_type:, content_length:, checksum:)
  instrument :url, key: key do |payload|
    generated_url = signer.signed_uri(
      uri_for(key), false,
      service: 'My azure storage,
      permissions: 'rw',
      expiry: format_expiry(5.days)
    ).to_s
    payload[:url] = generated_url
    generated_url
  end
end

def headers_for_direct_upload(key, content_type:, checksum:, **)
  { "Content-Type" => content_type, "Content-MD5" => checksum, "x-ms-blob-type" => "BlockBlob" }
end

private

def uri_for(key)
  blobs.generate_uri("#{container}/#{key}")
end

def blob_for(key)
  blobs.get_blob_properties(container, key)
rescue Azure::Core::Http::HTTPError
  false
end

def format_expiry(expires_in)
  expires_in ? Time.now.utc.advance(seconds: expires_in).iso8601 : nil
end

# Reads the object for the given key in chunks, yielding each to the block.
def stream(key)
  blob = blob_for(key)

  chunk_size = 5.megabytes
  offset = 0

  raise ActiveStorage::FileNotFoundError unless blob.present?

  while offset < blob.properties[:content_length]
    _, chunk = blobs.get_blob(container, key, start_range: offset, end_range: offset + chunk_size - 1)
    yield chunk.force_encoding(Encoding::BINARY)
    offset += chunk_size
  end
end

def handle_errors
  yield
rescue Azure::Core::Http::HTTPError => e
  case e.type
  when "BlobNotFound"
    raise ActiveStorage::FileNotFoundError
  when "Md5Mismatch"
    raise ActiveStorage::IntegrityError
  else
    raise
  end
end
```

end
end

What is the correct way to make the image URL publicly available?